# Get selected products summery from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, unpivot

I have a table1 where column names are there

| line | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | d |

Another table2 product sales

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| l | s | m | xs |
| xs | s | xs | m |
| m | xl | s | l |
| xs | xl | m | xl |
| xs | xl | l | s |
| xs | m | xl | l |
| m | m | l | l |
| s | m | m | l |

And I want a summery of products from table2 based on selected products in table1. Ay suggestion on this please?

The expected result looks like;

| product | sizes | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | l | 1 |
| a | xs | 4 |
| a | m | 2 |
| a | s | 1 |
| b | s | 2 |
| b | xl | 3 |
| b | m | 3 |
| d | xs | 1 |
| d | m | 1 |
| d | l | 4 |
| d | xl | 1 |
| d | s | 1 |

Comment: What do the rows in table2 represent?

Comment: Don't create columns for products.

Comment: Table2 has a horrible datamodel, you’d better fix that problem first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first linearize your sales table, by changing the schema from <a,b,c,d> to <product, sizes> using the `UNION ALL` as shown in the cte below.

Then you can:

- use `INNER JOIN` to filter your needed products,
- use `COUNT` to generate your qty field, by aggregating on both product and sizes

```
WITH cte_sales AS (
    SELECT 'a' AS product, a AS sizes FROM sales 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' AS product, b AS sizes FROM sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' AS product, c AS sizes FROM sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd' AS product, d AS sizes FROM sales
)
SELECT s.product, s.sizes, COUNT(s.sizes) AS qty
FROM       products  p
INNER JOIN cte_sales s
        ON p.product = s.product
GROUP BY s.product, s.sizes
ORDER BY s.product, s.sizes
```

If you know in advance you want only a, b and c sales, and want to avoid the join, you can also do as follows:

```
WITH cte_sales AS (
    SELECT 'a' AS product, a AS sizes FROM sales 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' AS product, b AS sizes FROM sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd' AS product, d AS sizes FROM sales
)
SELECT s.product, s.sizes, COUNT(s.sizes) AS qty
FROM cte_sales s
GROUP BY s.product, s.sizes
ORDER BY s.product, s.sizes
```

Output:

| product | sizes | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | l | 1 |
| a | m | 2 |
| a | s | 1 |
| a | xs | 4 |
| b | m | 3 |
| b | s | 2 |
| b | xl | 3 |
| d | l | 4 |
| d | m | 1 |
| d | s | 1 |
| d | xl | 1 |
| d | xs | 1 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dstHqTGa7bZbAeTvuZz4kp/0).

Comment: @ lemon  am getting the following error `UNION types text and integer cannot be matched`, any suggestion please? some of my columns are integer and some are text format. thanks

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, as the one at the bottom of my answer?

Comment: FYI please [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zq_Binic)

Comment: Cast `e` to your nvarchar value, like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/0CoNMvUN).